# NServiceBus 2.5.0.1442 Unit Testing Bus.CreateInstance<Interface> returning null in some unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nservicebus

I'm experiencing strange behaviour with NServiceBus Unit testing with Sagas.

Running

- NSB 2.5.0.1442 (Stuck here due to IMessage, and it being in multiple services)
- NServiceBus.Testing
- Resharper 8.2 unit test runner
- VS2013 update latest rtm version/package/thingy

I have three unit test projects in my solution. Only one of them is referencing NServiceBus.Testing, as it's the only one testing a Saga.

1. Messages.Testing
2. Service.Testing (This one references NSB.Testing)
3. ViewModelUpdater.Testing

Running unit tests projects individually everything works fine.

Running all three together introduces some test failures in Service.Testing. Even running all projects unit tests in debug mode gives the same issue.

I've backtracked the issue to this code. I've since added the command == null check to make the unit tests fail nicely, rather than returning silly rhino.mocks failures.

```
var command = Bus.CreateInstance<IEmailMessage>(a =>
{
    a.ToAddress = toAddresses;
    a.FromAddress = _formServiceEmailAddress;
    a.Subject = emailSubject;
    a.Body = body.ToString();
    a.IsHtmlBody = true;
});

if (command == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Email Message Failed to Create");
}

Bus.Send(command);
```

I haven't included the testing code, as i've removed my .ExpectSend code from the unit test, and it's still failing here.

```
Bus.CreateInstance<IEmailMessage> is returning null.
```

Bus is not null, I select all my unit tests projects and run debug.

In writing this question, i may be getting closer to solving the problem. The following comes from QuickWatch-ing Bus while debugging

```
((IBusProxyc9a2035def74446cb4f71fea5bf76c47)(Bus))
+       __interceptors  {Castle.Core.Interceptor.IInterceptor[1]}   Castle.Core.Interceptor.IInterceptor[]
```

Is it possible that "CreateInstance" has been proxied and doesn't work anymore? i don't use Bus.CreateInstance anywhere else in my saga, but this IEMailMessage is the only interface ( it's used by all our services to send to a standard email sender service.

I just reworked another of my messages to use Bus.CreateInstance<> but this time on an object, and got the same issue.

I reworked that same thing to Bus.Send and didn't get the same issue.

I'm now updating my original code to

```
Bus.Send<IEmailMessage>(a =>
{
    a.ToAddress = toAddresses;
    a.FromAddress = _formServiceEmailAddress;
    a.Subject = emailSubject;
    a.Body = body.ToString();
    a.IsHtmlBody = true;
});
```

Running the unit tests, now doesn't throw an exception on that code.

But now my unit tests are not passing my expectations.

```
InitiatedTestSaga(command)
    .ExpectPublish<FinanceUserAccessFormSubmitted>(m => CompareSubmitted(m,command) )
    .ExpectPublish<AssignedToManager>(m =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AssignedToManager");
        return m.FormId == command.FormId;

    })
    .ExpectSend<CreateFormSummary>(m =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CreateFormSummary");
        return m.FormId == command.FormId;

    })
    .ExpectSend<CreateFormHistory>(m =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CreateFormHistory");
        return m.FormId == command.FormId;

    })
    .ExpectSend<UpdateFormSummary>(m =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UpdateFormSummary");
        return m.FormId == command.FormId;

    })
    .ExpectSend<IEmailMessage>(m =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IEmailMessage");
        return TestCommands.ExpectedReceipientIs(m, command.FormDetails.ManagerForApproval.EmailAddress);
    })      
    .ExpectReply<CompletionMessage>(m => m.ErrorCode == (int) ResponseCode.Success)
    .When(s => s.Handle(command));
```

Output is

```
AssignedToManager
CreateFormSummary
CreateFormHistory
UpdateFormSummary
Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException : IBus.Send(callback method: <>c__DisplayClass2`1.<ExpectSend>b__1); Expected #1, Actual #0.
```

Which says IEmailMessage wasn't ever sent.

Is it possible that using Bus.Send<> is different than Bus.Send in behaviour? Is it possible that the ordering of the messages being sent is now different. In the saga code, the iemailMessage is the last message so should be the last message received by the unit test.

So to backtrack a bit. what happens when i run the test individually? here is the output for the same unit test

```
AssignedToManager
CreateFormSummary
CreateFormHistory
UpdateFormSummary
IEmailMessage
ExpectedReceipientIs__["Manager@domain.com"]
```

So we've still got a problem when all tests projects are run. I imagine if i change the order of the expectations, the test may work when running all, but then individually it will fail.

When changing the order of the IEmailMessage expectation, regardless of where i put it in the order (even in between the publish expectations) i get this error message

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'CreateFormSummary' to type 'IEmailMessage'.
```

So now my problem looks like it's not respecting that it's an interface. I'll replace IEmailMessage with a local class with the same properties

Created this

```
public class EmailMessage : IEmailMessage
{
    public string BCCAddress { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string CCAddress { get; set; }
    public string FromAddress { get; set; }
    public bool IsHtmlBody { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string ToAddress { get; set; }
}

//replaced IEmailMessage with concrete
Bus.Send<EmailMessage>(a =>
{
    a.ToAddress = toAddresses;
    a.FromAddress = _formServiceEmailAddress;
    a.Subject = emailSubject;
    a.Body = body.ToString();
    a.IsHtmlBody = true;
}); 

//Run All Unit tests 
//output of this unit test
AssignedToManager
CreateFormSummary
CreateFormHistory
UpdateFormSummary
IEmailMessage
ExpectedReceipientIs__["Manager@domain.com"]
```

Just for fun, decided to reverted my code back to Bus.CreateInstance to see if it still fails.

```
private void CreateAndSendEmail(string[] emailAddresses, string emailSubject, StringBuilder body)
{           
    string toAddresses = String.Join(",", emailAddresses);

    var msg = Bus.CreateInstance<IEmailMessage>(a=> 
    {
        a.ToAddress = toAddresses;
        a.FromAddress = _formServiceEmailAddress;
        a.Subject = emailSubject;
        a.Body = body.ToString();
        a.IsHtmlBody = true;
    })  ;

    if (msg == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("msg is null");
    }

    Bus.Send(msg);
}

//Run All Unit Tests
//output is this
AssignedToManager
CreateFormSummary
CreateFormHistory
UpdateFormSummary
IEmailMessage
ExpectedReceipientIs__
["Manager@wesleymission.org.au"]
```

### WTH?! it works

What have i done? I'm not sure.

I'm continuing to post this question because someone else may go through the hoops that i did. Also the NSB/particular team might appreciate the feedback.

### i'm not giving up that easily

Hang on, i'm not convinced i've done something wrong, let me try to break it again.

1. Close solution
2. delete all Debug folders,
3. delete all obj folders.
4. rebuild solution
5. close existing test sessions
6. re-run all unit tests -- Passes
7. run unit test projects individually -- Passes

So my concrete EmailMessages still exists, but i'm not referring to it anywhere anymore. so i can kill it.

1. Removed concrete EmailMessages
2. Rerun all unit tests -- FAILS!
3. run individually -- Passes

output of unit tests is

```
AssignedToManager
CreateFormSummary
CreateFormHistory
UpdateFormSummary
System.Exception : msg is null
```

Saga is calling in both instancesBus.CreateInstance

### Solution

Create an implementation of an interface and then not use it.

Comment: All I can suggest is moving to a newer version. So many bugs have been fixed since v2.5 it really isn't possible for us to support it. Version 3.2.8 which was released 2 years ago is the earliest version that we're still patching at this time.

Comment: Thanks Udi, we are planning an upgrade to NSB 4.5 at the moment. I'll update with results from that. Talking with Kimberley about licensing at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Create an implementation of an interface and then not use it.